# How to control a loop rate inside a node with RCLPY Rate object

Tags: ros2, rclpy, rate, thread, sleep

I'm quite new to ros2 and I'm trying to understand **how to control the rate of a loop** inside the main method of an action server.
There are many issues related to this topic but I think that none of them really answers this question, actually.

One of the most viewed on this platform, and also replicated in other websites is the following:

[Rate and sleep function in RCLPY library for ROS2](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/96684/rate-and-sleep-function-in-rclpy-library-for-ros2)

answered by @jacobperron. The solution shows how to sleep an 'entire' node from the main method.

What I'd like to achieve instead is using a sleep() function at the end of a while block in order to ensure the required rate and make the node/thread sleep.

In the above answer, the author suggests that another option is to spin in the main thread and poll the rate object to see if it is done. The related example is [this](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/blob/75c51c945d6029bea61571ced43c1d1b9c3c6703/rclpy/test/test_rate.py).
I'm wondering if, starting from this example, it is possible to implement the rate control of the while loop that I need.

Another very common answer is the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63169018/rate-and-sleep-function-in-rclpy-library-for-ros2

asnwered by @SmallJoeMan but I am not sure if I can use it as I'd like to.

Can anyone give me some help?

Thank you very much for your attention.